# IIS Map Network Drive to Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, drupal, symlink, virtual-directory

I'm working on setting up a Drupal 8 Site on IIS. On Linux, we commonly have a network share that all Load Balanced Nodes can access, and then a symlink to connect the directory /sites/default/files to that share. I need the same for IIS.

Things that didn't work:

1) Virtual Directory in IIS: We authenticated with a user on the AD, and we were able to load all files (i.e. the images on the site appear). However for some reason, Drupal couldn't see it and also created a folder "files" in the same directory, through the front end and IMCE I can only write to that folder and not the Virtual Directory. If someone knows a resolution here that would be helpful.

2) Regular Shortcut: Same problem as above. Drupal doesn't see the shortcut since it's actually named `files.lnk` when created through the file browser. It creates another folder ./files and refers to that instead of the shortcut.

3) Hard Links: I tried running this command `cmd /c mklink /J D:\inetpub\wwwroot\\web\sites\default\files "\\Public Files\files" and it simply stated "Local Volumes are required to complete this operation"

4) Soft Links: Changing up the switch on the previous command to `cmd /c mklink /d D:\inetpub\wwwroot\<site_dir>\web\sites\default\files "\\<share>\Public Files\files" works, but I'm only getting HTTP 401 errors in Chrome, even though I've allowed the Local Group IIS_IUSRS to have full control, plus opening it up to almost every user.`

Comment: "On Linux, we commonly have a network share". That's a bad design with unnecessarily increased network traffic (between web servers and file share), not only for Linux, but also for Windows. Copy those files to local disk on Windows is the only option you should consider.